# Unable to Install TA-Lib python library

Tags: ta-lib

I have python 3.6 version installed on my laptop. I am unable to install TA-Lib on my laptop using pip or any other method....

Can somebody please help?

Comment: What's the issue you are getting ?

Comment: ERROR: FAILED BUILDING WHEEL FOR TA-LIB.